# IndexError: list index out of range when using split in glob

Tags: python

I am getting the below error when I try to train a model on my local Windows PC. This error does not happen in Colab, so I think it's something related to the path or Linux.

I get the list out of index error when I try to call `label = labels_to_number(TRAIN_PATH)` in my main file

The snippet of the main file:

```
TRAIN_PATH = './data/train/'
.
.
.
.

labels = labels_to_number(TRAIN_PATH) #transform labels from string to number
```

The data_utils.py file:

```
def labels_to_number(path):
   
    classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[3] for i in glob.glob(path + '*')]
    classes.sort()

    labels_dict = {}
    for i, label in enumerate(classes):
        labels_dict[label] = i

    return labels_dict
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Project\train_model.py", line 28, in <module>
    labels = labels_to_number(TRAIN_PATH)
  File "E:\Project\data_utils.py", line 12, in labels_to_number
    classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[3] for i in glob.glob(path + '*')]
  File "E:\Project\data_utils.py", line 12, in <listcomp>
    classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[3] for i in glob.glob(path + '*')]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please help fix this problem
? Thank you.

Comment: you should check the list `i.split(os.path.sep)`. Propably the list have 3 items in the list and you cannot reach 4th index of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input: `TRAIN_PATH = './data/train/'` your `os.path.sep` appears three times, but in Python the index is counted starting at `0`

So your `split` input should be this:

```py
# TRAIN_PATH = './data/train/'
classes = [i.split(os.path.sep)[2] for i in glob.glob(path + '*')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you supplied a relative data path the list generated from

```
i.split(os.path.sep)
```

will have less elements and that's why it throws an error